# The maximum value of input_ids (50257) must be smaller than the embedding layer's input dimension (50257)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, transformer-model, gpt-2

I am trying to create a categorical model that produces one of the three result for some data input: True, False, Invalid.

as mentioned in the title I get this error when I try to evaluate the model, here is a code in the
model_tokenizer.py file:

```py
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer
import torch
import pandas as pd
import sys


def convert_to_df(file:str):

    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df.dropna(subset=['Data'],how='all',inplace=True)
    return df


def tokenize_and_encode(df, file_name):


    gpt2_tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
    gpt2_tokenizer.add_special_tokens({"pad_token": "[PAD]"})


    df['Data'].fillna('', inplace=True)

    df['data_tokens'] = df['Data'].apply(
        lambda data: gpt2_tokenizer.tokenize(data))


    df['data_codded'] = df['data_tokens'].apply(
        lambda content_token: gpt2_tokenizer.encode_plus(content_token,
        return_tensors='tf', return_attention_mask=True,max_length=1024, truncation=True,padding='max_length')
    )




    df.to_excel(file_name)
    return df


pd_obj = convert_pandas('datasets/somefile.xlsx') 

data = tokenize_and_encode(pd_obj, 'outputfile.xlsx')
```

the code above successfully tokenize and encode the data

the 2nd file is responsible for creating the actual model and training it, in `model_creation.py` file:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from transformers import TFGPT2Model
from model_tokenizer import data
import numpy as np

def model_setup(df,):


    df['data_input_ids'] = df['data_codded'].apply(lambda data:data['input_ids'])
    df['data_atten_mask'] = df['data_codded'].apply(lambda data:data['attention_mask'])


    df.to_excel('dataset.xlsx')

    return np.array(df['data_input_ids'].tolist()),np.array(df['data_atten_mask'].tolist())



def data_model(*args):
    try:

        gpt_model = TFGPT2Model.from_pretrained('gpt2')
        data_input_ids_shape = tf.shape(args[0])
        data_attention_mask_shape = tf.shape(args[1])

        data_input_ids = tf.reshape(args[0], (data_input_ids_shape[0], data_input_ids_shape[2]))
        data_attention_mask = tf.reshape(args[1], (data_attention_mask_shape[0], data_attention_mask_shape[2]))

       
        data_inputs = {
            'input_ids': data_input_ids,
            'attention_mask': data_attention_mask
        }
        
        data_embedding = gpt_model([data_inputs]).last_hidden_state
        data_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(data_embedding)
    



        concatenated_embed = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([data_embedding,])

        output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu)(concatenated_embed)
        output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='veracity_layer')(output)

        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[data_input_ids, data_attention_mask, ], outputs=output)


        labels = tf.constant([0,1,2],dtype = tf.int32)
        labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=3)

        
        features = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
            (args[0],args[1])
    
    ))
        

        labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
            labels
        ))

        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((features,labels))

    
        sampling = len(args[0])
        train_size = int(sampling*0.7)
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=samples, seed=40, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

        train_dataset = dataset.take(train_size)

        test_dataset = dataset.skip(train_size)

        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        validation_steps = len(test_dataset)
        model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=5, validation_data=test_dataset, validation_steps=validation_steps)

        test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_dataset)

        print(f'The loss is : {test_loss}, The Acc is : {test_accuracy}')
    except Exception as e:
        with open('log.txt','w') as log:
            log.write(str(e))



    



data_input_ids, data_atten_masks = model_setup(data)

data_model(data_input_ids,data_atten_masks)
```

and the error i get in `log.txt` is:

```
Exception encountered when calling layer 'transformer' (type TFGPT2MainLayer).

The maximum value of input_ids (50257) must be smaller than the embedding layer's input dimension (50257). The likely cause is some problem at tokenization time.
Condition x < y did not hold.
First 3 elements of x:
[25104  5644   326]
First 1 elements of y:
[50257]

Call arguments received by layer 'transformer' (type TFGPT2MainLayer):
  � input_ids={'input_ids': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(20, 1024), dtype=int32)', 'attention_mask': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(20, 1024), dtype=int32)'}
  � past_key_values=None
  � attention_mask=None
  � token_type_ids=None
  � position_ids=None
  � head_mask=None
  � inputs_embeds=None
  � encoder_hidden_states=None
  � encoder_attention_mask=None
  � use_cache=True
  � output_attentions=False
  � output_hidden_states=False
  � return_dict=True
  � training=False
```

when i tried to figure out at which line the error happen using `sys` module, it seemed to happen at this line:

`data_embedding = gpt_model([data_inputs]).last_hidden_state`

any help is appreciated.